# External ressource in webpage gives 403 online, but works in local. Is there a way to fix?

Tags: html, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to embed an image from another website in my webpage. The image link is in http (not ssl). When launching the page in local, the image shows correctly, but when i try to put the webpage online, the image request gives a 403 Forbidden error, on every hosts I tried.

I have difficulty to understand how it works in local but not online.
Is there a way to bypass this 403 error?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the server is preventing you from embedding that image on your site. This is known as [hotlinking prevention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking#Server_side).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to bypass the hotlinking protection by using the cURL library in php:

I added this php file "imagegrabber.php" in the same directory as my html webpage

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image");
$url = $_GET['url'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.1 Safari/537.11');
$res = curl_exec($ch);
$rescode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($ch) ;
echo $res;
?>
```

and in my html page I call this php snippet like that:

```
<img src="imagegrabber.php?url=http://www.externalwebsite.com/protectedimage.jpg">
```